# C++\CLI - How to set a member function as a handler to xmlDocument::Schemas::ValidationEventHandler

Tags: .net, xml, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to set a member function as a handler to a XmlDocument data member in C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2012.  The handler function looks like this...

```
void Validate ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException ) {

            switch ( xmlException->Severity ) {

                case System :: Xml :: Schema :: XmlSeverityType :: Error : {

                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( "Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( " Error: {0}", xmlException->Message );

                } break;

                case System :: Xml :: Schema :: XmlSeverityType :: Warning : {

                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( " Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( "Warning: {0}", xmlException->Message );

                } break;

                default : {

                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( "An unknown XML Exception has occured:\n\n   Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
                    System :: Console :: WriteLine ( "Exception: {0}", xmlException->Message );

                } break;

            }

        };
```

...which is nothing special.

This is what my data member looks like...

```
System :: Xml :: XmlDocument ^ xmlDocument;
```

...and this is how I'm trying to set it in the class constructor:

```
xmlDocument->Schemas->ValidationEventHandler += gcnew System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ( this, & MyClass :: Validate );
```

My problem is I receive error C3767: candidate function(s) are not accessible, even though my "Validate" member function and the class it is defined in is specified as public.

I've tried a number of approaches, most recently working off of EventArgs or employing "#pragma make_public ( System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs )", but to no avail.

I'm running out of hair to pull out of my head, so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Where are you loading the schema into the schema collection?  You have to specify a schema to validate against.

Comment: I have an instance of XmlDocument in my class, which to my understanding has a schema collection in it as part of its composition (Schema and SchemaInfo properties).  Would I need an external reference or something?

Comment: You need to explicitly specify the schema (e.g. add the `.xsd` to the `Schemas` collection).  The schema is not resolved automatically just by loading the XmlDocument - unless you're expecting consumers of your class to populate the Schemas collection. In other words, you have to tell validate what to validate against.

Comment: So your saying load the .xml file prior to injecting the event handler?  If so I'll give a go straight away

Comment: I added a bit more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the reason you are getting compiler error C3767 is that you need to do:

```
schemas->ValidationEventHandler += gcnew System::Xml::Schema::ValidationEventHandler(this, &MyClass::Validate);
```

Instead of `gcnew ValidationEventArgs`.

Secondly, be aware that `XmlSchemaSet.ValidationEventHandler` may not do what you think.  From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.validationeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Sets an event handler for receiving information about schema validation errors when the Add or Compile methods of the XmlSchemaSet are called.

Thus if you're looking to add an event handler for an invalid XML document, this isn't it.  It's for errors in the schema itself.

If you're looking to make a class that wraps an `XmlDocument` but also allows callers to load schemas and validate the `XmlDocument` against it, you could do something like this:

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        xmlDocument = gcnew System::Xml::XmlDocument();
        schemas = gcnew System::Xml::Schema::XmlSchemaSet();
        // Set the callback for errors in the schema itself.
        schemas->ValidationEventHandler += gcnew System::Xml::Schema::ValidationEventHandler(this, &MyClass::ValidateSchema);   
        xmlDocument->Schemas = schemas;
    }

    // Adds a schema to the current schema set.
    void AddSchema(System::String ^targetNamespace, System::String ^schemaUri);

    // Loads the specified document, validating it against the current schema set.
    void LoadDocument(System::String ^inputUri);

    // Validates the current document against the current schema set.
    void ValidateDocument();

    System::Xml::XmlDocument ^ GetDocument() { return xmlDocument; }

private:
    // Validation callback for errors in the schema itself.
    void ValidateSchema ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException );

    // Validation callback for errors in the XML document.
    void ValidateXml ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException );

    // Lower level callback for both schema and XML errors.
    void Validate ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException, System::String ^ prefix );

    System::Xml::XmlDocument ^ xmlDocument;

    System::Xml::Schema::XmlSchemaSet ^schemas;
};
```

It is convenient to cache the `XmlSchemaSet` separately because, when an `XmlDocument` is initialized with XML data from an `XmlReader`, the [`XmlDocument.Schemas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.schemas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object is (re)loaded from the `Schemas` property of the reader.

Then a prototype implementation would look like:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#using <mscorlib.dll>
#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Xml.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Xml;
using namespace System::Xml::Schema;

void MyClass::AddSchema(System::String ^targetNamespace, System::String ^schemaUri)
{
    try
    {
        schemas->Add(targetNamespace, schemaUri);
        xmlDocument->Schemas = schemas;
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->ToString());
        // Possibly rethrow.
    }
}

void MyClass::LoadDocument (System::String ^inputUri)
{
    XmlReader^ reader = nullptr;
    try
    {
        ValidationEventHandler^ eventHandler = gcnew System::Xml::Schema::ValidationEventHandler(this, &MyClass::ValidateXml);  

        XmlReaderSettings^ settings = gcnew XmlReaderSettings();

        settings->Schemas = schemas;
        settings->ValidationType = ValidationType::Schema;
        settings->ValidationEventHandler += eventHandler;

        reader = XmlReader::Create(inputUri, settings);

        xmlDocument->Load(reader);
        reader->Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex)
    {
        Console::WriteLine(ex->Message);
        // Possibly rethrow.
    }
    finally
    {
        // Make sure the reader is closed in the event of an exception.
        delete reader;
    }
}

void MyClass::ValidateDocument()
{
    ValidationEventHandler^ eventHandler = gcnew System::Xml::Schema::ValidationEventHandler(this, &MyClass::ValidateXml);

    xmlDocument->Validate(eventHandler);
}

void MyClass::ValidateSchema ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException)
{
    Validate(sender, xmlException, gcnew System::String("Schema: "));
}

void MyClass::ValidateXml ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException )
{
    Validate(sender, xmlException, System::String::Empty);
}

void MyClass::Validate ( System :: Object ^ sender, System :: Xml :: Schema :: ValidationEventArgs ^ xmlException, System::String ^ prefix )
{
    switch ( xmlException->Severity ) 
    {
    case System :: Xml :: Schema :: XmlSeverityType :: Error : 
        {
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + "Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + " Error: {0}", xmlException->Message );

        } break;

    case System :: Xml :: Schema :: XmlSeverityType :: Warning : 
        {
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + " Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + "Warning: {0}", xmlException->Message );

        } break;

    default : 
        {
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + "An unknown XML Exception has occured:\n\n   Object: {0}", sender->ToString () );
            System :: Console :: WriteLine ( prefix + "Exception: {0}", xmlException->Message );

        } break;
    }
};
```